# Can I cancel a Yapapi task by contact a yagna REST endpoint?

Tags: yagna

I have a container running a requestor inside, and I was wondering if I could send a HTTP request to that container to somehow stop a currently running task. Is there any built in method in Yagna or Yapapi that will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question! Assuming you are referring to a single task or group of tasks launched in a Golem execute_tasks call, the answer is **No**, you cannot directly and completely cancel a task using the REST API. (prove me wrong!, see about me at end)

However, a task can be *indirectly* cancelled (but subsequently retried) by *terminating* its associated agreement via the REST API!, provided you can discover (*presumably* by means other than the REST API) a task's associated agreement id.

Terminating an agreement to cancel and retry a task can be done via a POST http method. I give an example below.

use this reference to see the available endpoints and affirm for yourself:

- https://github.com/golemfactory/yagna/tree/0.9_to_master/core/market/src/rest_api

---

**read on only if you want to see an example of how to hack a cancel and retry**

---

pre: container is running on 192.168.1.100 and yagna daemon on port 7465

the key to making this work is discovering a task's agreement id. here i show how obtaining the agreement id is possible indirectly by monitoring events in the requestor script. alternatives may include monitoring for new ***activities*** in the yagna daemon log file and parsing the associated activity id.

Given that every task is associated one-to-one bidirectionally with an agreement id, i will describe how to terminate a *specific* agreement and consequently cancel and retry its task one at a time with said id.

Here is how cancelling (and retrying) a specific task by way of terminating its agreement can be done in the context of the task model with curl for example in a bash script

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# terminate_agreement.sh
# YAGNA_APPKEY is set in the environment
AGREEMENT_ID=$1
IPADDR_CONTAINER=192.168.1.100
curl http://$IPADDR_CONTAINER:7465/market-api/v1/agreements/$AGREEMENT_ID/terminate?timeout=300 -H "Authorization: Bearer $YAGNA_APPKEY" -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '{"message": "into the void!"}' # -X POST implied
```

This will throw an exception of ***many types*** depending on the lifecycle phase of the task in its executing worker function (the callback given as the first argument to `golem.execute_tasks`). Because of the myriad of exception types, it is difficult to handle this specifically. That said, it may be possible to associate the Task object in context of the exception with its agreement id; then, one could inspect the state of the agreement - and this would have to be done for the general case of any exception. Given however the current Task class attributes, distinguishing the exception and identifying whether the running task has been remotely cancelled is no small problem with the current api, imho.

example run:

```sh
$ terminate_agreement.sh 5bb68e8bc8cd726ef9ecb45395e6c0797dcadf4ff5c2d049c9c1a82ccebfe4f7

# will respond with 200 for OK and this will show up in the yagna daemon log as:
[2021-12-29T19:09:55.882-0800 INFO  ya_market::negotiation::common] Requestor 'original' [0xb9cee14d2f31b4fd551ef041f81359084ce0d3a7] terminated Agreement [R-5bb68e8bc8cd726ef9ecb45395e6c0797dcadf4ff5c2d049c9c1a82ccebfe4f7]. Reason: 'into the void!'
```

One way to discover and associate agreement ids with tasks is by subclassing yapapi.log.SummaryLogger and overriding log as in:

```py
# inside class definition of base class SummaryLogger
        def log(self, event: yapapi.events.Event) -> None:
                if isinstance(event, yapapi.events.AgreementCreated):
                        print(f"{event.provider_info.name} is working on a task with agreement id of: {event.agr_id}", file=sys.stderr)
```

but to make this work (remotely) a separate program would need to monitor this broadcasted information (e.g. via IPC, sockets, etc). Here i have just printed it to stderr. This, however, does not solve the problem of distinguishing one running task from another in the script context...

references:

- https://github.com/golemfactory/yagna/blob/0.9_to_master/core/market/src/rest_api/common.rs
- https://yapapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#yapapi.Golem.execute_tasks
- https://yapapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=summarylogger#yapapi.log.SummaryLogger
- https://github.com/golemfactory/yapapi/blob/master/yapapi/events.py
- https://github.com/golemfactory/yapapi/blob/f3345ef9c23518b4b3a49455461a384f44280078/yapapi/executor/task.py#L23

**i expect in the future there will be more endpoints and convenience functions along with documentation to facilitate cancelling one or more tasks remotely!**

about yagna:

> yagna stands for yet another golem network agent. it is the daemon
> that powers the distribution of computations and services across a limitless number
> of cpus serving as nodes on the golem network. learn how to leverage
> or profit from this innovative model at https://www.golem.network

about me:

> hi, i'm krunch3r and i am a process oriented individual, therefore, i
> continually edit as i prove myself wrong and encourage others to prove
> me wrong on any of my observations! if you do, please be polite. that
> said, someone else may wish to describe how agreement ids can be
> discovered via the REST API itself, e.g. by remotely obtaining the
> pertinent event information from the daemon directly from REST
> responses. in that case, the answer is a little more generalized;
> nevertheless, the id still needs to be identified.